# Como percorrer uma árvore dinâmica em javascript definindo o valor de suas propriedades?

Tags: javascript, json

Boa noite, eu possuo a seguinte árvore definida pelo JSON:

```
  [
       {
          "roleName":"CCA",
          "children":[
             {
                "roleName":"Data_Final_Índices_CCA",
                "$$hashKey":"object:2183",
                "children":[
                   {
                      "roleName":"Datas_Índices_CCA",
                      "$$hashKey":"object:2192"
                   }
                ],
                "collapsed":true
             },
             {
                "roleName":"Data_Inicial_Índices_CCA",
                "$$hashKey":"object:2184",
                "children":[
                   {
                      "roleName":"Datas_Índices_CCA",
                      "$$hashKey":"object:2195"
                   }
                ],
                "collapsed":true
             },
             {
                "roleName":"IGPM",
                "$$hashKey":"object:2185"
             }
          ],
          "$$hashKey":"object:2179",
          "collapsed":true
       }
    ]
```

Cada nó "pai" pode ter n filhos e todos os filhos podem ter outros filhos.

Preciso setar o valor "false" em todos os nós com a a propriedade "collapsed", para isso preciso percorrer todos os nós, como posso fazer isso usando alguma função em Javascript? A arvore não possui tamanho nem quantidade de nós fixos.

Comment: Edite a pergunta e coloque um [mcve] com sua tentativa em abordar o problema. Anexe as mensagens de erro e tente destacar em que linha acha que o código está dando erro.

Answer (score 2):

A maneira mais simples, é converter esse objeto numa *String* e mudar o texto com uma RegExp. Ten a vantagem adicional de não alterar o objeto inicial.

```js
const obj = [{
  "roleName": "CCA",
  "children": [{
      "roleName": "Data_Final_Índices_CCA",
      "$$hashKey": "object:2183",
      "children": [{
        "roleName": "Datas_Índices_CCA",
        "$$hashKey": "object:2192"
      }],
      "collapsed": true
    },
    {
      "roleName": "Data_Inicial_Índices_CCA",
      "$$hashKey": "object:2184",
      "children": [{
        "roleName": "Datas_Índices_CCA",
        "$$hashKey": "object:2195"
      }],
      "collapsed": true
    },
    {
      "roleName": "IGPM",
      "$$hashKey": "object:2185"
    }
  ],
  "$$hashKey": "object:2179",
  "collapsed": true
}];

const modificado = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj).replace(/"collapsed":true/g, '"collapsed":false'));

console.log(modificado);
```

A maneira mais complexa é criar uma função recursiva que procure essas chaves e mude o valor. O problema que isso pode gerar é mudar o objeto internamente e caso esse objeto seja usado noutro código ele não ser o que se está à espera. Podes sempre criar uma cópia antes com `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));`.

```js
const obj = [{
  "roleName": "CCA",
  "children": [{
      "roleName": "Data_Final_Índices_CCA",
      "$$hashKey": "object:2183",
      "children": [{
        "roleName": "Datas_Índices_CCA",
        "$$hashKey": "object:2192"
      }],
      "collapsed": true
    },
    {
      "roleName": "Data_Inicial_Índices_CCA",
      "$$hashKey": "object:2184",
      "children": [{
        "roleName": "Datas_Índices_CCA",
        "$$hashKey": "object:2195"
      }],
      "collapsed": true
    },
    {
      "roleName": "IGPM",
      "$$hashKey": "object:2185"
    }
  ],
  "$$hashKey": "object:2179",
  "collapsed": true
}];

function recursiveSetter(obj, key, newValue) {
  if (typeof obj !== 'object') return;
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => {
    if (k === key) {
      obj[key] = newValue;
    } else {
      if (typeof obj[k] === 'object') {
        recursiveSetter(obj[k], key, newValue);
      }
    }
  });
}

recursiveSetter(obj, 'collapsed', false);

console.log(obj);
```